# IV regression in Fixed-Effect Models with diagnostics

Tags: r, regression, plm, fixest

I want to do an IV regression in Fixed-Effect Models with diagnostics (Wu-Hausman, weak instrument, etc.).  I tried three options, each with its problem--

y is dependent variable

x1 is the endogenous independent variable

c1, c2, c3 are control variables

inst is the instrument variable

City and Year are two factors for fixed effects

1. ivreg

`fit_ivreg = ivreg(data, y ~ x1 + c1 + c2 + c3 + City + Year | inst + c1 + c2 + c3 + City + Year)`

`summary(fit_ivreg, diagnostics = T)`

The problem of this model is that I am not sure if this is fixed-effect model at all.

2. plm

`fit_plm = plm(data, y ~ x1 + c1 + c2 + c3 | inst + c1 + c2 + c3, effect = "twoways", model = "within", index = c("City", "Year"), inst.method = 'baltagi')`

`summary(fit_plm)`

This works, but there is no statistical diagnostics at all.

3. fixest

`fit_fixest = feols(data, y ~ c1 + c2 + c3 | City + Year | x1 ~ inst)`

`summary(fit_fixest)`

There is diagnostics.  But the output result of this model is COMPLETELY different from that of my plm model above.  I am really confused.

Comment: It is helpful to provide minimal data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for `plm` or `fixest`. Those packages are made for panel model, e.g. fixed effects and instrumental variables. I think you should set `effect=individual`, twoway is different. See how to define panel IDs and then select the fe, default is individual oneway effects. It can also be time oneway effect or both, twoway effects.

```
# Fixed Effects Instrument Variables

# Data
data("Produc", package = "plm")

# PLM 
library(plm)

model_plm <- plm(pcap ~ unemp + water + util | water + util + pc + gsp, 
    data=Produc, effect = "individual", model = "within", index=c("state", "year"))

model_plm$coefficients

     unemp      water       util 
80.0067927  0.8989423  1.3288631 

# FIXEST
library(fixest)

model_iv_fe <- feols(pcap ~ water + util | state | unemp ~ pc + gsp, 
Produc, panel.id = ~ state + year)

model_iv_fe$coefficients

 fit_unemp      water       util 
80.0067927  0.8989423  1.3288631
```

See, the estimates are identical.

So, you already gave the answer to your question. *`fixest` does panel estimation with instruments and reports nice diagnostics*.

You can read more about package differences in SE: [R plm vs fixest package - different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69488168/r-plm-vs-fixest-package-different-results)